# Call a controller in asp.net using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a discussion panel in which I am going to post the comment and want to save it in database through controller and using the following code

```
$("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
                var strdata = $("problemID").val() + $("empID").val() + $("#_1").val() + "0" + "0";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    URL: <%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %>,
                    data: 'strdata',
                    dataType: "bool",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success" + msg);
                    }


                })
        })
```

or I am also trying

```
 var url = "/Controllers/DiscussionController/PostComment";

            $.post(url, { comment: "abc" }, function (data) {
                alert("d");
            })
```

but not getting the results

Comment: What does your action look like?

Comment: In my controller DiscussionController.cs contains the function public bool PostComment(String pFormData)
        {
            return false;
        } and i want to execute this function by this line <%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %> but it is not running

Comment: Have you marked the method PostComment with the [HttpPost] attribute?  It will not respond to a "POST" otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the `url` in quotes as it is a string and the variable(`strdata`) should not be in quotes.

Also the data that you send to server should be in key/value pair format. Looking at your data it doesn't make any sense. I have modified `strdata` as well take a look. Add the data parameters in that way.

```
$("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
    var strdata = {
       problemID: $("problemID").val(),
       empID: $("#_1").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %>",
        data: strdata,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success" + msg);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: In my controller DiscussionController.cs contains the function public bool PostComment(String pFormData)
        {
            return false;
        } and i want to execute this function by this line <%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %> but it is not running

Comment: Also note that the hash key "URL:" needs to be lowercase, "url:"

Comment: Do you see the call being made?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `strdata` var not "strdata" string

```
$("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
    var strdata = $("problemID").val() + $("empID").val() + $("#_1").val() + "0" + "0";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion", strdata)  %>',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success" + msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In my controller DiscussionController.cs contains the function public bool PostComment(String pFormData)
        {
            return false;
        } and i want to execute this function by this line <%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %> but it is not running

Comment: @Snake. I updated the code. You really should ask yourself why are you  send AJAX post to an action that return false..

Answer (score 0):

The variable strdata should be passed as a variable, not in quotes. And the URL should be in quotes. Also, I think your selectors are incorrect that are going into strdata. You should have # in front of them if they're ID's.

```
$("#btnPostComment").click(function () { 
    var strdata = $("#problemID").val() + $("#empID").val() + $("#_1").val() + "0" + "0"; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        URL: "<%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %>", 
        data: strdata, 
        dataType: "bool", 
        success: function (msg) { 
            alert("Success" + msg); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: In my controller DiscussionController.cs contains the function public bool PostComment(String pFormData)
        {
            return false;
        } and i want to execute this function by this line <%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %> but it is not running